# Load invoice by invoice id and invoice increment id

Tags: magento2, invoice

I have an invoice id or an invoice increment id, is there a way to load an invoice using these?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
private $invoice;

public function __construct(
    ....
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice $invoice
) {
    ....
    $this->invoice = $invoice;
}

....
....

// load invoice using entity id
$invoice = $this->invoice->load('1');
// OR
// load invoice using increment id
$invoice = $this->invoice->loadByIncrementId('000000001');

print_r($invoice->getData());
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```
public function __construct(
    .....
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice $invoice,
    .......
) {
    ...
    $this->invoice = $invoice;
    ........
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}


public function getInvoiceDetails($incrementId){

    $invoiceDetails = $this->invoice->loadByIncrementId($incrementId);
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($invoiceDetails->getId()); exit;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to use the invoice interface:

```
    use Magento\Sales\Api\InvoiceRepositoryInterface;

    private $invoiceRepository;

    public function __construct(
     ...
        InvoiceRepositoryInterface $invoiceRepository
     ...
    ){
        $this->invoiceRepository = $invoiceRepository;
    }
     
    public function myCustomFunction($invoiceEntityId)
    {
        $invoice = $this->invoiceRepository->get($invoiceEntityId);
    }
```